# Cannot change foreground color in sublime with Mac

Tags: sublimetext3

Many of the instructional videos I've seen on youtube for changing color schemes has been on PC.  They tell me that I have to change the file monokai.default-color-scheme or something like that which is in sublime folder but on a Mac things are not like.  In /library/app support/sublime text 3/packages/user/  - there is only one file, the setting file.  I cannot file that says 'monokai.default-color-scheme' on a Mac.  In any case, I have a setting files

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.sublime-color-scheme",
    "font_face": "Times New Roman",
    "font_size": 21,
    "line_numbers": false,
    "open_files_in_new_window": false,
    "save_on_focus_lost": true,
    "theme": "Adaptive.sublime-theme",
    // "foreground":"hsl(120,54%,45%)",
    "foreground":"#008000",
}
```

And all those changes have worked well, but not the foreground changes.  I use sublime text just like a text editor.  I use Pycharm for coding.  I like the way that sublime puts all the tabs in one location.  When I want to do something complicated I use Word, but most of the time Sublime is all I need, but I can't change the foreground text.  I'm trying to make all of the text green. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps and instructions for modifying a color scheme apply similarly to Windows, MacOS and Linux, with the only difference being the location in which you put the resulting file that you're modifying, because the location of user configurable files is different from OS to OS.

From your description it sounds like you're expecting to see the color scheme file to modify in your `User` folder, but that is not the case (or at least, not always).

In your example, your `color_scheme` is set to the `Monokai` color scheme which, as the path shows, is not in the `User` package. Most packages are installed as `sublime-package` files, so you will not find a file by that name anywhere on your system should you look.

What you want to do is choose `UI: Customize Color Scheme` from the command palette (or, if you are using an older build of Sublime that does not provide this command, install [PackageDev](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev) ; it provides `PackageDev: Edit Current Color Scheme`, which does the same thing).

Either command will open a new window with the default color scheme in an uneditable window on the left, and on the right is the content of your current color scheme modifications. If you don't have any yet, this will show you an empty file that you can use as the base for your modifications.

Adding changes to the right hand file and saving will augment the color scheme and immediately take effect.

From there, you can use the instructions from whatever tutorial you were using to make the modifications that you want.

Note that the file that you create on the right is always in `sublime-color-scheme` format (a JSON file) even if the color scheme you're using is a `tmTheme` file (an XML file).

Comment: When I open the command palette and type UI: Customize Color Scheme, nothing comes up.

Comment: I can't get get color scheme to open with an unalterable file on the left.  I have a file which is unalterable on the left but I think that's the settings, that's how I changed the font.

Comment: If you don't have the `UI` command to edit the color scheme, then you're running an older build of Sublime; in that case you can upgrade to a newer version, or install `PackageDev` as outlined above; it provides a command that does the same thing.